# Trying to create function that interpolates a float to zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lerp

I am trying to create a smooth function to interpolate a number to zero. Problem is, it isn't working. In this case, if I increase a number by 0.01 a specified number of times, I want to decrease that number by 0.02 until it is zero. Here is my function.

```
float ReduceSpeed(float x)
{
    if (x != 0f)
    {
        if (x % 0.02f != 0 && x > 0)
        {
            x = x - 0.01f;
        } else if (x % 0.02f != 0 && x < 0)
        {
            x = x + 0.01f;
        }
        else
        {
            if (x > 0f)
            {
                x = x - 0.02f;
            }
            else
            {
                x = x + 0.02f;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

I want to use this to create a kind of sliding motion in unity.

Comment: Do not use modulo (%) operator for floating point numbers, unless you really need it and know its limitations. It's almost never needed.

Comment: Is there any reason why you avoid Lerp or SmoothDamp?

Answer (score 2):

The problem most likely lies in the line

```
if (x != 0f)
```

`x` is very likely to not be exactly zero due to rounding errors, since 0.01 and 0.02 are periodic numbers in base 2. You should choose a small value (epsilon) that you would compare the absolute value of `x` against, e.g.

```
if (Math.Abs(x) < 1E-10)
```

Comment: Or [`Mathf.Approximately()`](http://ws.cis.sojo-u.ac.jp/~izumi/Unity_Documentation_jp/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)